# Can one change/influence JAXB's code generation?

Tags: jaxb

I was wondering whether one can influence the "style" of the code that JAXB generates from XML schema (.xsd) fles. E.g. I would like to:

- emit a comment inside newly generated classes, specifically if the class is empty, since that triggers warnings in my environment.
- change all setter-methods to return the object instead of "void", so one can do call-chaining like:

X someMethod() {
    return new X().setFoo(5).setBar("something");
}

instead of the tedious:

X someMethod() {
  X x = new (X);
  x.setFoo(5);
  x.setBar("something");
  return x;
}

Is there some "template" anywhere that JAXB uses and that one could tweak, to achieve such things? Or is that all hard-coded?

M.

Answer (score 0):

There is no template for modifying the generated code easily.

There is, however, a number of plugins. For instance: https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Fluent-api which is just what you want according to your 2nd bullet.

There are other plugins, e.g. for annotations suppressing warnings - that may help against the 1st bullet.

As an extra, I'd like to mention that not generating Java classes from an XML schema but writing them by hand (plus annotations, of course) is a plausible alternative, provided the XML schema isn't too complex. It may have other advantages besides solving #1 and #2.

Comment: I went to said page and the docs look promising, indeed, so I wanted to download and experiment with that JAXB2_RI & plugins. I downloaded the "Distribution with dependencies" from page http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Home (which I found via the above link) but I can't get that beast to run! I always only get "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.inheritance.InheritancePlugin could not be instantiated". Apparently this needs even further .jar's beyond those that are included in the download. Where do I find those?